# Obtaining Probabilities in KNN Classifier in R

Tags: r, probability, knn

I have the following the data set:

`TRAIN` dataset

```
   Sr      A       B       C     XX
    1   0.09    0.52    11.1    high
    2   0.13    0.25    11.1    low
    3   0.20    0.28    11.1    high
    4   0.29    0.50    11.1    low
    5   0.31    0.58    11.1    high
    6   0.32    0.37    11.1    high
    7   0.37    0.58    11.1    low
    8   0.38    0.40    11.1    low
    9   0.42    0.65    11.1    high
    10  0.42    0.79    11.1    low
    11  0.44    0.34    11.1    high
    12  0.45    0.89    11.1    low
    13  0.57    0.72    11.1    low
```

`TEST` dataset

```
   Sr      A       B       C     XX
    1   0.54    1.36    9.80    low
    2   0.72    0.82    9.80    low
    3   0.19    0.38    9.90    high
    4   0.25    0.44    9.90    high
    5   0.29    0.54    9.90    high
    6   0.30    0.54    9.90    high
    7   0.42    0.86    9.90    low
    8   0.44    0.86    9.90    low
    9   0.49    0.66    9.90    low
    10  0.54    0.76    9.90    low
    11  0.54    0.76    9.90    low
    12  0.68    1.08    9.90    low
    13  0.88    0.51    9.90    high
```

`Sr`  : Serial Number

`A-C` : Parameters

`XX`  : Output Binary Parameter

I am trying to use the KNN classifier to develop a predictor model with 5 nearest neighbors. Following is the code that I have written:

```
train_input <- as.matrix(train[,-ncol(train)])
train_output <- as.factor(train[,ncol(train)])
test_input <- as.matrix(test[,-ncol(test)])
prediction <- knn(train_input, test_input, train_output, k=5, prob=TRUE)
resultdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(test[,ncol(test)], prediction))
colnames(resultdf) <- c("Actual","Predicted")
```

`RESULT` dataset

```
    A   P
1   2   2
2   2   2
3   1   2
4   1   1
5   1   1
6   1   2
7   2   2
8   2   2
9   2   2
10  2   2
11  2   2
12  2   1
13  1   2
```

I have the following concerns:

1. What should I do to obtain probability values? Is this a probability of getting high or low i.e. P(high) or P(low)?
2. The levels are set to 1 (`high`) and 2 (`low`), which is based on the order of first appearance. If `low` appeared before `high` in the train dataset, it would have a value 1. I feel this is not good practice. Is there anyway I can avoid this?
3. If there were more classes (more than 2) in the classifier, how would I handle this in the classifier?

I am using the `class` and `e1071` library.
Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this just involve using `table` and `prop.table`???

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm relatively new to R.

Comment: `prop.table(table(RESULT))`

Answer (score 0):

Utility function built before the "text" argument to scan was introduced:

```
rd.txt <- function (txt, header = TRUE, ...) 
{    tconn <- textConnection(txt)
    rd <- read.table(tconn, header = header, ...)
    close(tconn)
    rd}

 RESULT <- rd.txt("    A   P
 1   2   2
 2   2   2
 3   1   2
 4   1   1
 5   1   1
 6   1   2
 7   2   2
 8   2   2
 9   2   2
 10  2   2
 11  2   2
 12  2   1
 13  1   2
 ")

> prop.table(table(RESULT))
   P
A         1       2
  1 0.15385 0.23077
  2 0.07692 0.53846
```

You can also set up prop.table to deliver row or column proportions (AKA probabilities).